# Is Hadoop Suitable For This?

Tags: postgresql, hadoop

We have some Postgres queries that take 6 - 12 hours to complete and are wondering if Hadoop is suited to doing it faster.   We have (2) 64 core servers with 256GB of RAM that Hadoop could use.

We're running PostgreSQL 9.2.4.  Postgres only uses one core on one server for the query, so I'm wondering if Hadoop could do it roughly 128 times faster, minus overhead.

We have two sets of data, each with millions of rows.

Set One:

```
id character varying(20),
a_lat double precision,
a_long double precision,
b_lat double precision,
b_long double precision,
line_id character varying(20),
type character varying(4),
freq numeric(10,5)
```

Set Two:

```
a_lat double precision,
a_long double precision,
b_lat double precision,
b_long double precision,
type character varying(4),
freq numeric(10,5)
```

We have indexes on all lat, long, type, and freq fields, using btree.  Both tables have "VACUUM ANALYZE" run right before the query.

The Postgres query is:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    setone one
WHERE
    not exists (
        SELECT
            'x'
        FROM
            settwo two
        WHERE
            two.a_lat >= one.a_lat - 0.000278 and 
            two.a_lat <= one.a_lat + 0.000278 and
            two.a_long >= one.a_long - 0.000278 and 
            two.a_long <= one.a_long + 0.000278 and
            two.b_lat >= one.b_lat - 0.000278 and 
            two.b_lat <= one.b_lat + 0.000278 and
            two.b_long >= one.b_long - 0.000278 and 
            two.b_long <= one.b_long + 0.000278 and
            (
                two.type = one.type or
                two.type = 'S'
            ) and
            two.freq >= one.freq - 1.0 and
            two.freq <= one.freq + 1.0
        )
ORDER BY
    line_id
```

Is that the type of thing Hadoop can do?  If so can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Lots of detail missing to get a good answer. What version of postgresql? What do your tables look like? Have you ANALYZED them? Have you indexed the lat and long? Have you looked at PostGIS? Are you able to split the query into logical units that can run in parallel?

Comment: And why haven't you just split the query into grids? It looks very geographically constrained. That's got to be less effort than porting the whole system over to hadoop.

Comment: I updated the question with more detail about the Postgres version, tables, and indexes.  I'll try with PostGIS.  I'm not familiar with splitting the query into logical units.  Can you explain more about that?

Comment: @RichardHuxton Can you explain more about splitting the query into grids (for me, and others that see this post later)?  Maybe an example query?

Comment: Just separate your world into grids of lat/lon - restrict the one table, rely on the indexes to hit the second table then merge the results at the client. Presumably what hadoop would do.

Comment: After querying where are you planning to keep the data? Or you are planning to keep the data at all?

Comment: Are the tables rows of coordinates that form linestrings? If so, definitely look into PostGIS for a much faster solution. These could be Linstring, or LinesringM (measure) geometry types, complete with R-tree spatial indexes and lots more. Also, the +/- 0.000278 parts look questionable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Stado at http://stado.us. Use this branch: https://code.launchpad.net/~sgdg/stado/stado, which will be used for the next release.

Even with 64 cores, you will only be using one core to process that query. With Stado you can create multiple PostgreSQL-based "nodes" even on a single box and leverage parallelism and get those cores working.

In addition, I have had success converting correlated not exists queries into WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) ...) = 0.

Comment: Stado looks very interesting.  I'll definitely do some testing with that. Thanks

Comment: I ended up using Postgres-XC, rather than Stado, and had to break it up into simple queries (do the outer query, loop over the results and build the inner query using those values), but was able to get the results in 23 minutes instead of 8+ hours.  It ends up being 100k+ little queries, but they run very quickly.  Stado wouldn't do the complex query, so I moved on to XC (which did the complex query, but took 15+ hours).  I haven't taken the time to try Stado with the simple queries, but I'm sure it would work and perform well.

Answer (score 2):

I think `Hadoop`is very apropriate for that, but consider using `HBase` too.

You can run a Hadoop `MapReduce`routine to get data, treat it and save it in a optimal way to `HBase` table. That way, reading data from it would be really faster.

Comment: I agree with this answer. You can also check out Hive if you want SQL-like interface, but not real-time analytics

Answer (score 0):

Pure Hadoop isn't suitable because doesn't have indexes. HBase implementation is very tricky in this case because only one key is possible per table. Anyway they in best case both of them requires 5 servers at least to feel significant improvement. The best that you can do with PostgreSQL is to partition data per type column, use second server as replica of the first one and execute several queries in parallel for each particular type.
To be honest PostgeSQL isn't a best solution for that. The SybaseIQ(the best) or Oracle Exadata (in worse case) can do it much better because of columnar based data structure and BLOOM filtering.